# how to isolate a part of car model in simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have a simulink car model which includes different part of a car obviously (subsystems):). I want to isolate a part of this model, for example, brakes, and feed in dummy variable as inputs.

My problem is that this model has few bus selector and creator, which makes it a little bit complicated. I wonder how I can isolate the brakes part without messing up the buses.

Answer (score 1):

When you say isolate, do you mean you want to move the contents of the subsystem into a separate model?  If so, one way to do this is to use the "Convert to Model block" tool.  To use this,

1. Make sure the subsystem is atomic (set_param(subsys, 'TreatAsAtomicUnit','on');).
2. Right-click on the subsystem and choose **Convert to Model block**.
3. The tool might ask you to make a few changes to the model.
4. At the end of the process, you will have a new model with the contents of the subsystem, and the tool will create any bus objects that are needed.